# Glew and Glut how do you activate pixel format?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

So I've come to c++ Glew and Glut from java LWJGL. And I've got a spinning rectangle with simple glBegin(GL_QUADS) and that stuff working. But how do i activate pixel format like in LWJGL.

Comment: What does it mean to "activate" a pixel format? You've already got a framebuffer here and the default framebuffer is immutable (you're stuck with whatever format you started with).

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is [`glutInitDisplayMode()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html#SECTION00033000000000000000) on/off flags:

> - `GLUT_RGBA`: Bit mask to select an RGBA mode window. This is the default if neither GLUT_RGBA nor GLUT_INDEX are specified.
> - `GLUT_RGB`: An alias for GLUT_RGBA.
> - `GLUT_INDEX`: Bit mask to select a color index mode window. This overrides GLUT_RGBA if it is also specified.
> - `GLUT_SINGLE`: Bit mask to select a single buffered window. This is the default if neither GLUT_DOUBLE or GLUT_SINGLE are specified.
> - `GLUT_DOUBLE`: Bit mask to select a double buffered window. This overrides GLUT_SINGLE if it is also specified.
> - `GLUT_ACCUM`: Bit mask to select a window with an accumulation buffer.
> - `GLUT_ALPHA`: Bit mask to select a window with an alpha component to the color buffer(s).
> - `GLUT_DEPTH`: Bit mask to select a window with a depth buffer.
> - `GLUT_STENCIL`: Bit mask to select a window with a stencil buffer.
> - `GLUT_MULTISAMPLE`: Bit mask to select a window with multisampling support. If multisampling is not available, a non-multisampling window
>     will automatically be chosen. Note: both the OpenGL client-side and
>     server-side implementations must support the GLX_SAMPLE_SGIS extension
>     for multisampling to be available.
> - `GLUT_STEREO`: Bit mask to select a stereo window.
> - `GLUT_LUMINANCE`: Bit mask to select a window with a ``luminance'' color model. This model provides the functionality of OpenGL's RGBA
>     color model, but the green and blue components are not maintained in
>     the frame buffer. Instead each pixel's red component is converted to
>     an index between zero and glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_COLORMAP_SIZE)-1 and
>     looked up in a per-window color map to determine the color of pixels
>     within the window. The initial colormap of GLUT_LUMINANCE windows is
>     initialized to be a linear gray ramp, but can be modified with GLUT's
>     colormap routines.

You can't request a specific number of alpha/depth/stencil/etc. bits like you can with [LWJGL's `PixelFormat`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat.html).

Comment: i already currently have a line: glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH); so what do i do now?

Comment: @Kid8: ...nothing?  You've already configured the pixel format as much as GLUT will let you.